# How to stop Safari on iOS highlight the whole image?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, mobile-safari

In order to have responsive images on a web-site, I am using `overflow: hidden` style on the image's container, with other rules related to max-height and automatic width so for the given screen width images have the same ratio on the visible area, almost no matter what is the image itself. And it works with landscape images well.

However, some portrait-oriented images have long hidden area, and when you tap the link on the image in iPhone's Safari, it will show (highlight) the whole extent of the image in addition to Save and other options' menu.

Markup used is roughly this:

```
<figure>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <a href="...">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400/">
    </a>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Styles (excerpt, without widths and unrelated):

```
a {
   max-width: 900px;
   max-height: 120px;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: block;
}
div {
   max-width: 900px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   max-height: 120px;
}
img {
   width: 100%;
}
```

At first I thought, that it is because `<a>` fills `<img>`, so I've added `display: block` and `max-height`, but it does not help. This means, that tap menu is for the image, and full image is hightlighted.

Is there any way to show only visible part in tap highlight?

Comment: I cannot test it but try giving the image `pointer-events: none;` declaration. E.g. (`a img { pointer-events: none; }`).

Comment: @HashemQolami please, write as an answer so I can acknowledge, because it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to give [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) declaration the image element.

It prevents the image from being the target of the pointer (on click/tap).

For instance:

```css
a img { pointer-events: none; }
```

It's worth noting that `pointer-events` [is supported in iOS Safari 3.2+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).